# How to describe the difference in number?

Tags: grammar

There are 15 boys and 10 girls in a class. 
Is it grammatically correct to say "there are 5 more boys than girls in the class" or "the boys are more than the girls by 5" or "there are 5 boys more than girls"?
How to say?

Comment: Only the first one is idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one sounds most idiomatic to me.  Although I am not a grammar expert, I do not see any glaring grammatical *error* with the others, per se, they just sound a bit odd.